# Drop Collection Before Closing Connection Using Async and Await Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to clear a collection in my database prior to loading it with data and then closing the connection. I am using MongoDB with Mongoose for the database. My code is as follows:

```
function closeConnection() {
  return mongoose.connection.close()
}

function dropCollections() {
  return People.collection.drop()
}

async function doItAll() {
  await dropCollections()
  await closeConnection()
}

doItAll()
```

`People` is a mongoose model. I was under the impression that the await statement would wait for the initial promise to resolve before moving on, but what happens is the connection to the database closes before the collection can be dropped. What is the proper way to achieve this? Can I do it using async and await?

One thing I noticed is that `People.collection.drop()` returns undefined, but shouldn't the result still be resolved before the connection closes?

Comment: do `mongoose.connection.close()` and  `People.collection.drop()` return a promise? if not, then await does nothing useful for you - async/await is "syntactic sugar" for Promise, not a catch-all for asynchrony

Comment: `mongoose.connection.close` does but `People.collection.drop()` does not. How can I "wait" for the drop before closing though? It seems like it behaves asynchronously regardless

Comment: you'll need to "promisify" `People.collection.drop`

Comment: Alright, I'll try the `util.promisify` from Node

Comment: According to [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#drop), `drop` does return a promise?

Comment: Try it for yourself, I am using the mongoose driver for mongoDB and can tell you that nothing is returned from `model.collection.drop()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this once, if not resolved yet:

```
async function closeConnection() {
  return mongoose.connection.close();
}

async function dropCollections() {
  return People.collection.drop();
}

async function doItAll() {
  const result = await dropCollections();
  if (result) console.log("Collection dropped");
  await closeConnection();
}

doItAll();
```

The `await` keyword will "wait" for Promise functions. Since `collection.drop()` is a Promise but `dropCollections()` is not, you can declare it as a promise-like function, so the purpose is served.